a real function $f(x)$ with $\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(\zeta)f'(\zeta)f''(\zeta)f'''(\zeta)\geq0$
The explicit problem is: if a real function $f(x)$ has the continuous third-order derivative over $\mathbb{R}$ then $\exists\,\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(\zeta)f'(\zeta)f''(\zeta)f'''(\zeta)\geq0$.
If $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ have zeros over $\mathbb{R}$ then it is proved. So suppose $f(x)>0$ identically. But I have no ideas about the latter part of the proof, could you give me some hints?

if I understood correctly, this is a falsifiability.
take the function: $e^{-x}$
which all its values positive.
its derivative is: $-e^{-x}$
which all its values are negative.

But then $f(x)f'(x)f''(x)f'''(x)=e^{-4x}\geq0$ holds, the problem is that their product is $\geq0$, not individually $\geq0$.

See: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1572934p9666815

FYI, using an Approach0 search, in addition to finding the AoPS thread that geetha290krm has indicated, there are also f(a)f'(a)f''(a)f'''(a)>=0, f has continuous third derivative and function and calculus.... (with it having just one "answer" which points to the AoPS thread ...

(cont.) 1998 Putnam A3).

"If $f'''(x)<0$ then $f''(x)>f''(0)$ for all $x<0$ and so there exist an $r>0$ such that $f'(-r)<f'(0)-rf''(0)=0$, contradiction." How does the author get the inequality $f'(-r)<f'(0)-rf''(0)=0$?

If not, there exists some $f\in C^3(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
  P[f]:=ff'f''f'''<0\quad {\rm in}\ \ \mathbb{R}.
$$
This implies $f^{(i)}\ (i=0,1,2,3)$ has no zero in $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, the two transformations $T_1:\ f\mapsto -f$ and $T_2:\ f(x)\mapsto \tilde{f}(x):=f(-x)$ keep the sign of $P$, that is, $P[T_if]<0\ (i=1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then we may assume $f>0$ and $f'>0$ (If $f<0$, consider $T_1f$; If $f'<0$, consider $T_2f$). If $f''<0$, then $f$ is concave. It means the graph $Gr(f)$ of $f$ is below the tangent line of any point in $Gr(f)$. Since $f'\not=0$, then there exists some points $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)<0$. It leads to a contradiction! Hence, $f''>0$. Similarly, repeating the above process for $f',f''$ to obtain $f'''>0$. It yields
$$
  ff'f''f''>0,
$$
which is a contradiction! As a result, for any $f\in C^3(\mathbb{R})$, there exists some point $\zeta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
  ff'f''f'''\ge0\quad {\rm at}\ \ \zeta.
$$
